# ADO error "Current Recordset does not support updating. This may be a limitation of the provider, or of the selected locktype."

Tags: asp-classic

I am doing some calculation with the data set I take from my database. Null values give errors so I tried replacing null values with zeros(0). Here is the error I get,

> ADODB.Recordset error '800a0cb3'
>
> Current Recordset does not support
>   updating. This may be a limitation of
>   the provider, or of the selected
>   locktype.

Never seen it before. Here is my code.

```
If IsNull(objRevenueToday("REVENUE")) Then
    objRevenueToday("REVENUE") = 0
End If
```

Comment: It would have really helped if you had posted which DB you are using.

Answer (score 2):

Your recordset appears to be read-only.  There could be a number of reasons for this; you're reading a view that contains a Group By clause, you don't have permissions, etc.

Comment: Agreed, How did you open your database?  Was the ADO cursor Readonly?

Answer (score 1):

Using the syntax `Set Recordset = Command.Execute` always opens a read only cursor. What you need to do is open the cursor using the `Recordset` object. The `Source` parameter of the `Open` method is your `Command` object. This allows you to set the desired location and locktype.

```
Dim cmdProc as ADODB.Command
Dim rsData as ADODB.Recordset

Set cmdProc = New ADODB.Command
With cmdProc
Set .ActiveConnection = SomeConnection
.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
.CommandText = "selCustomer"
' ... Create parameters
End With

Set rsData as New ADODB.Recordset
rsData.Open cmdProc,, adOpenStatic,adLockBatchOptimistic 
'...Process recordset data.
```

Comment: rsData.Open cmdProc,, adOpenStatic,adLockBatchOptimistic

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```
If IsNull(objRevenueToday("REVENUE")) Then
RevenueToday = "0"
Else
RevenueToday = objRevenueToday("REVENUE")
End If
```

Not very ideal but fixed my error.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming SQL Server (although similar techniques available in other DBs.

Change the query so that is will not return nulls in records.  For example in the T-SQL

```
 SELECT ISNULL(REVENUE, 0), .... FROM ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the settings as below. It force the client side cursor...It worked for me

```
set pagedlistrs=CreateObject("adodb.recordset")
pagedlistrs.cursorlocation = 3 ' adUseClientpagedlistrs
pagedlistrs.Open SQL, objConn, 3,3,1
```